# Search with multiply searchwords

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want a search form which search my whole db. The search form should be consist of several input and select tags.

Atm it shows me after the submit every possible combination of columns and rows.

Here the search fom part:

```
<div style="width:1420px" class="wmfg_layout_2">
    <form action="xxx.php" method="post">
        <ul class="wmfg_questions">
            <li class="wmfg_q">
            <label class="wmfg_label">Suchkriterien auswählen</label>
                <table class="wmfg_answers">

                    <tr class="wmfg_a">
                    <th>

                        <td><label class="wmfg_label_a" for="chk_search1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;search1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="search1" size="25"></td>

        </th>
                    <th>

                        <td><label class="wmfg_label_a" for="chk_search2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;search2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="search2" size="25"></td>

        </th>
        <th>

                    <td><label class="wmfg_label_a" for="chk_search3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Status&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td>
                    <td>

                    <select name="search3" size="1">
                    <option disabled selected value> </option>;

            <?php
            foreach($result as $m)
            {

            echo "<option value=\"" . $m['resultID'] . "\">" .$m['result'] . "</option>";

            }
        ?>

        </td>
        </select>

                    </th>

        <th>
                    <td><label class="wmfg_label_a" for="chk_search4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;search4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td>
                    <td>

                    <select name="search4" size="1">
                    <option disabled selected value> </option>;

            <?php
            foreach($result2 as $m)
            {

            echo "<option value=\"" . $m['result2ID'] . "\">" .$m['result2'] . "</option>";

            }
        ?>


                    </th>
                    <th>

                    <td><label class="wmfg_label_a" for="chk_search5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;search&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label></td>
                    <td>

                    <select name="search5" size="1">
                    <option disabled selected value> </option>;

            <?php
            foreach($result3 as $m)
            {

            echo "<option value=\"" . $m['resul3ID'] . "\">" .$m['result3'] . "</option>";

            }
        ?>

        </tr>
                    </th>

                    </table>
        </td>
        </select>

                    </th>
                            </li>
                            <li class='wmfg_qEnd'>
                                <input type='submit' name='suche' value='Anfrage senden'>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                </tr>
    </form>

</div>
```

Always the same results, when i use for example search and search1 or only search5 etc. and submit it, it shows me all column and row combination as results and not the lines i want when i search for my key words
i think i have to split the search terms and echo it with conditions, but dont know how. 
Here is the php part code:

```
<?php
        $search1=$_POST['search1'];
        $search2=$_POST['search2'];
        $search3=$_POST['search3'];
        $search4=$_POST['search4'];
        $search5=$_POST['search5'];
        $search = $connection->query("SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col5, col6, col7, col8 FROM table1, table2, table3
        WHERE table1.col1 LIKE '%".$search1."%'
        OR table1.col2 LIKE '%".$search2."%'
        OR table1.col3 LIKE '".$search3."'
        OR table1.col4 LIKE '".$search4."'
        OR table1.col5 LIKE '".$search5."'");



    $search->execute();
    $result = $search->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    if (isset($_POST['search1'])
        or isset($_POST['search2'])
        or isset($_POST['search3'])
        or isset($_POST['search4'])
        or isset($_POST['search5'])){ 



            foreach ($result as $row2) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row2['col1']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row2['col2']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row2['col3']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row2['col4']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row2['col5']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row2['col6']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row2['col7']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row2['col8']."</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }


    $connection = null;
?>
```

The second part of the PHP code which call the query.

This is an example table for table1 reduced in colums only for the understanding, it has much more columns and rows.

table1

```
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| PK_ID | name | FK_ID_TB2 | FK_ID_TB3 |  status  |
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|     1 | TC   |         1 |         1 | on hold  |
|     2 | HTS  |         2 |         2 | finished |
|     3 | HTOL |         3 |         3 | on going |
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

this is table2

```
+-------+------------+
| PK2_ID| technology |
+-------+------------+
|     1 | bla        |
|     2 | bli        |
|     3 | blubb      |
+-------+------------+
```

and here table3

```
+-------+------------+
| PK3_ID| assignment |
+-------+------------+
|     1 | assign1    |
|     2 | assign2    |
|     3 | assign3    |
+-------+------------+
```

I have 5 mechanism to search entrys its a filter - 2 inputs form fields and 3 selection. And when i submit i want to display all records with my entered criteria.

For exmaple when i search for 'TC' the results should be:

```
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| PK_ID | name | technology | FK_ID_TB3 |  status  |
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|     1 | TC   |        bla |    assign | on hold  |
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

When i search for 'TC' and 'on going' it should be display row1 and row3 etc..

Is the question is understandable? Thx for help in advance. Have a nice day.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, please clarify your question, maybe provide an example?

Comment: Please read about ["SQL Injection"](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Your code is vulnerable.

Comment: i have 5 different search  inputs and selections, i want to search for entrys in my db, in combination or sometime only with one input word.

Answer (score 1):

Here i update my answer You can use LOCATE instedof % and check for empty value check code bellow :

```
 if(!isset($_POST['search1']))
   $_POST['search1']='';


   if(!isset($_POST['search2']))
   $_POST['search2']='';


    if($_POST['search1'] == '')
             $search1='';
     else 
             $search1=" LOCATE('".$_POST['search1']."',t1.name)>0 OR "

  if($_POST['search2'] == '' )
             $search2='';
     else 
             $search2=" LOCATE('".$_POST['search2']."',t1.status)>0 OR "



                $search3=$_POST['search3'];
                $search4=$_POST['search4'];




    $connection->query("
    SELECT t1.PK_ID , t1.name , t2.technology, t3.assignment, t1.status FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
            WHERE 
              t1.FK_ID_TB2=t2.PK2_ID 
            AND
               t1.FK_ID_TB2=t3.PK3_ID 
            AND
            (
               ".$search1."
               ".$search2."
             t2.technology = '".$search3."'
            OR t3.assignment = '".$search4."'

            )");
```

Here a example depend your values http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/027509/1

Comment: ok @Daniel it sames i anderstand where is the problem try  my answer again and see if it work

Comment: isnt working for me and no var_dump($result) thanks for the time put in here

Comment: you welcome brother , it sames i forget to put ' caracter on search1 and search 2 i update now hope it work

Comment: interesting side, i will play a bit with it. i work with microsoft sql